# Is there a built in Python/pandas function to rename duplicate columns in a pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a DataFrame with columns with the same name:

```
x x y
2 5 1
1 9 3
4 1 2
```

Is there built-in general function to rename columns with the same name to differ from each other?
Example of a possible result:

```
x0 x1 y
2  5  1
1  9  3
4  1  2
```

When reading a csv with pandas.read_csv automatically does this (defaulting mangle_dupe_cols=True) but I could not find a handy way to do this to a DataFrame object already in Python.

Comment: Yes, it will add when duplicate name found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but I could not find a handy way to do this to a DataFrame object already

To an existing dataframe we have to resort to some code, there is no builtin;

```
s = pd.Series(df.columns)
df.columns= df.columns+s.groupby(s).cumcount().replace(0,'').astype(str)

   x  x1  y
0  2   5  1
1  1   9  3
2  4   1  2
```

Comment: This solution seems to only work since my example DataFrame has the same number of rows and columns. Using it on a DataFrame with 4 rows raises the error:
ValueError: Length of passed values is 3, index implies 4
This makes the solution not generalizable.

Comment: @Dennix updated my second solution, please refer that, sorry for the troubles

Comment: I accepted your answer but you should edit or remove the first solution too.